# Dell Latitude D610 USB ports not functioning

Tags: usb, lubuntu

Installed clean install of Lubuntu 18.04.5 on my old Dell Latitude D 610 and everything works great except I can't seem to get any of my usb sticks to work with it. Tried "susb -l" and it seemed to show all four ports but no recognition of even the oldest usb stick I have. There should be 1-usb2 and 3-usb1. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the startup logs to see how your system sees the USB ports at startup with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you plug in your USB sticks.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: Do note; your hardware won't run anything later than Lubuntu 19.04 as I used a dell latitude d610 in QA-testing for Lubuntu.. You should have no issues with the OS & USB unless you've done something to stop that from working, so I'd suggest booting a *live* system & ensuring the USB ports still work; and haven't been friend because you pulled out USB cable & shorted wire as power connected as you forgot to safely dismount. If you can't boot USB *live* system, boot *live* off HDD but inability to boot a USB *live* system will indicate USB ports maybe *fried*... My 2c

Comment: Don't forget USB media is *consumable*, ie. *somewhat* low quality as made to cost & dies rather easily on *frequent* writing...